# why the saved facebook username in Parse is a random string rather than real username?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

So, I used Parse for the first time for log-in to my iOS app, and the username that is saved in Parse is something like 4fn1XaL3eFA6VJtCRA5eLlcia. What is this string and where does it come from? and why the actual username is not saved?

Comment: It is a unique identifier for the Facebook user. It's just how it works, it's not customizable. Facebook users have no use for a username and password - they have to log in with Facebook to log into your app.

Comment: I seem to having the same problem. The email field is undefined, too.